# Shared RelativeLayout transitions between two fragments

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to make a Fragment Relative_layout animation between two fragments. but the whole fragment is animating.please help me
here is my code.

from fragment 'A' i am calling this, relative_layout is a "RelativeLayout"

```
            // Check that the device is running lollipop
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                setSharedElementReturnTransition(TransitionInflater.from(getActivity()).inflateTransition(R.transition.change_image_transform));
                setExitTransition(TransitionInflater.from(getActivity()).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.explode));

                // Create new fragment to add (Fragment B)
                EmailLogInPage emailLogInPage = new EmailLogInPage();
                emailLogInPage.setSharedElementEnterTransition(TransitionInflater.from(getActivity()).inflateTransition(R.transition.change_image_transform));
                emailLogInPage.setEnterTransition(TransitionInflater.from(getActivity()).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.explode));



                // Add Fragment B
                fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.container, emailLogInPage)
                        .addToBackStack("transaction")
                        .addSharedElement(relative_layout, "profile");
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
```

this is my layout

```
        <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:transitionName="profile"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:id="@+id/login_with_mail"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_without_color"
        android:layout_height="40dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
            android:alpha="0.3"
            >

        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_box_round"
            android:alpha="0.05">

        </RelativeLayout>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/mailp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:text="Login with Mail"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: http://www.androidauthority.com/using-shared-element-transitions-activities-fragments-631996/

Comment: thanx!!!!!! its working